# Python script to retrieve access token from API via Resource owner password credential grant

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I am using SOAPUI to retrieve data from an API which use access token.
The Access Token in SOPAUI is getting refreshed using "Resource owner password credential grant".

Now in Python I can fetch data using the access token with below code.

```py
import requests
import json

auth_token='MY_TOKEN'
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth_token}'}

url = 'https://MYURL_and_Paramter?_limit=10000&_pageNav=true&_out=JSON'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.json())


with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
json.dump(response.json(), f)
```

However mow I need a script to retrieve the token as well where authorization type is Resource owner password credential grant.
Below are the credential getting used in SoapUI to generate the token.

```
Oath 2 flow: "Resource owner password credential grant"
Resource Owner Name: "somename"
Resource Owner Password: "somepassword"
Client Identification: "SomeID"
Client Password: "SomePassword"

Access token URL: "URL"
Scope : blank
```

Now when I am trying to get the information, I am getting error 403, Below is the code I tried so far:

```py
import json
import requests

data = { "username" : "somename", "password":"somepassword"}
                                                                                                                                       
headers = {"Client_id": "SomeID", "Client_secret": "SomePassword", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
                                                                                                  
response = requests.get("https://URL/as/token.oauth2", data=data, headers=headers)
if response.status_code in [200]:
    tok_dict = json.loads(response.text)
    print(tok_dict)
    issued_at = tok_dict["issued_at"]
    expires_in = tok_dict["expires_in"]
    token_type = tok_dict["token_type"]
    access_token = tok_dict["access_token"]
else:
    print("error")
    print(response.status_code)
```